# Проблема с библиотекой Worlize

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, websocket, php

Я недавно начал использовать Ratchet и все шло хорошо, до попытки работы с Flash. Как мне посоветовали в другом вопросе, можно использовать библиотеку Worlize.

Но после подключение WebSocket сервера и запуска приложения, начинаются выкрики с ошибками, ужасные не то слово.

```
typecheck com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$/hashToBase64()
  outer-scope = [global Object$]
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()
  0:getlocal0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O])
  1:pushscope
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  2:pushbyte 0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I])
  4:convert_u
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (uint[U])
  5:setlocal 7
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  7:getglobalscope
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (global~[O])
  8:getslot 1
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$[O])
  10:getlocal1
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$[O] String[S])
  11:callproperty ::createBlocksFromString 1
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (Array[O])
  15:coerce Array
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (Array[O])
  17:setlocal2
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  18:findpropstrict ::hashBlocks
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O])
  21:getlocal2
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] Array[O])
  22:callproperty ::hashBlocks 1
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (flash.utils::ByteArray[O])
  26:coerce flash.utils::ByteArray
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (flash.utils::ByteArray[O])
  28:setlocal3
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  29:pushstring ""
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (String~[S])
  31:setlocal 4
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  33:getlocal3
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (flash.utils::ByteArray[O])
  34:pushbyte 0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (flash.utils::ByteArray[O] int[I])
  36:setproperty position
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  39:pushbyte 0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I])
  41:setlocal 5
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  43:jump 72
------------------------------------
MERGE FIRST B72:       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
------------------------------------
B72:                   [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  72:getlocal 5
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I])
  74:getlocal3
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I] flash.utils::ByteArray[O])
  75:getproperty length
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I] uint[U])
  77:iflt 47
------------------------------------
MERGE FIRST B47:       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
------------------------------------
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  81:findpropstrict mx.utils::Base64Encoder
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (Object~[A])
  84:constructprop 1232 0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (*[A])
  88:coerce mx.utils::Base64Encoder
 --- Connection Failure: There was an error while parsing the following HTTP Header line:
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 9O0zTdhja/+zIbgEwB3eXEYhM/o=
 --- Disconnected
```

Как это можно исправить? Очень буду благодарен.

Comment: Сдается мне, что параметр Sec-WebSocket-Accept неправильно зашифрован, так как не получается его расшифровать

Comment: Я вот если правильно понял, то ругается он на:

private function generateNonce():void {
 nonce = new ByteArray();
 for (var i:int = 0; i < 16; i++) { nonce.writeByte(Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF));
 }
 nonce.position = 0;
 base64nonce = Base64.encodeByteArray(nonce);
}

Comment: Может быть, я неправ, но мне кажется, это проблема на Flash-стороне. Но, к сожалению, по коду на AS помочь не могу.