# Различие в декодировании Flex и Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Интересует вопрос, почему в Adobe Flash CS6 возникает проблема, описанная в данном вопросе ([Проблема с библиотекой Worlize](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/267035/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-worlize)), а в Adobe Flex Bulder 4.5 подобной ошибки нету и проходит все идеально. Как это исправить?

Comment: Вопрос описан крайне просто, да и сам он выглядит туго, кроме как воспроизводить у себя с исходниками выхода не вижу. Или хотя бы шаги по повторению проблемы у себя.

Comment: Все довольно просто. Запускаю тестовое приложение от Worlize (https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket). Именно с ним такая проблема.

Шаги простые, скачал, открыл, перекинул com папку в проект и попробовал скомпилировать. В Adobe Flash CS6 выскакивает ошибка, описанная в вопросе, ссылка на который в первом сообщении. А в Adobe Flex Builder 4.5 подобной ошибки нету, все запускается и работает.

Мне же необходимо это все как-то запустить без ошибок в Adobe Flash.

Comment: проверьте наличие в библиотеках класса  mx.utils::Base64Encoder

и swc - as3corelib.swc

Comment: Спасибо большое, отсутствовал класс Base64Encoder.

Comment: Не за что.